# Dictionary in a child class to update the dictionary with same name defined in parent class instead of over-riding

Tags: python

I have existing classes which inherit from each other…they already have a attribute which is being overridden in subclasses . I want the dictionary attribute to be updated instead of overridden…code below …

```
class A:
  d = {1:2}

class B(A):
  d = {3:4}


b=B()

print b.d[1]
2
print b.d[3]
4
```

Is this possible at all? Say using metaclasses in a way that I can't think of readily.

Comment: Why would you do that? Class B is not related to class A at all.

Comment: -1 Question is very unclear.

Comment: @Simeon Visser: Oops..missed the inheritance

Comment: Ideally the solution adds something to class A since the subclasses are many and I would not want to replicate the update code in every subclass

Comment: Inheritance is not a good tool for achieving code reuse! For reuse, you should [prefer composition over inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this based on some of the ideas around:

class B(A):
    _d = {}

```
def __init__(self):
    for parent_klass in inspect.getmro(self.__class__):
        _d.update(getattr(parent_klass, 'd', {}))
    _d.update(self.d)
    self.d = _d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A(object):
    d = {1:2}

class B(A):
    d = {3:4}
    def __init__(self):
        dtemp = self.d
        self.d = A.d.copy()     # warning: shallow
        self.d.update(dtemp)

b=B()
print b.d[1]
# 2
print b.d[3]
# 4
a=A()
print a.d[1]
# 2
print a.d[3]
# KeyError
```

Comment: You've understood my question, though I had it wrong…problem is I have a deep class hierarchy and I would like somehow the base init to handle this…so that any subclass can benefit from the additional attributes

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit, I'd say.  Maybe let A have a method `add_atributes` which is to be called by derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what exactly you're trying to do here, but looks like [`collections.ChainMap`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.ChainMap) may come in handy if you're on py3.3+:

```
from collections import ChainMap
...
dic = ChainMap(B.d, A.d)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> dic[1]
2
>>> dic[3]
4
```

Any modification done to either `A.d` or `B.d` would reflect in `dic`

```
>>> A.d[4] = 5
>>> dic[4]
5
```

Modifying the dict itself would modify `B.d`(First dict passed to `ChainMap`):

```
>>> dic[6] = 7
>>> B.d
{3: 4, 6: 7}
```